# Error when set project in release mode - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Am porting my Windows Phone 8 app to Windows Phone 8.1 and everything is working fine in debug mode. But when I set in release mode and while building the application, I get the error,

- The type of namespace "FlickGestureEventArgs" could not be found
- The type of namespace "ShakeGestureEventArgs" could not be found

How to overcome this? I couldn't launch the app certification kit when in debug mode.

Comment: Does the project contain any [`#if DEBUG` or similar directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)?

Comment: Ya I have, but those lines are commented.

Comment: The only reason I can think of for this change in behavior is if one of the directives is only conditionally declaring a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution for my own question and here is my answer.

First I re-installed the WP toolkit from nuget using the command

> Install-Package WPtoolkit

So that I can able to solve **FlickGestureEventArgs**. And similarly I thought this will be solution to my another problem **ShakeGestureEventArgs**. Started searching for the new ShakeGesture.dll and find that in below link.

> [ShakeGesture.dll](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmox989izt1tbht/ShakeGestures.rar)

Now my problem is solved. If you are facing the same issues, just re install the packages which shows error and you can able to solve it.

Comment: Why did this change between Release and Debug? I thought packages were shared.

Comment: As per the guidelines, we need to set the app package in release mode. So I tried with that.